# What does 'limb' mean for a legal judgment?

Tags: meaning

[*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSullivan-Hilliards-Law-Contract-Janet/dp/0198807821/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (2018 8 ed). p 65

> 3.53 As regards the second **limb**, *Smith v Hughes* said that actual knowledge is required. The
>   fact that the claimant should have known the defendant meant to contract for old oats
>   would not be enough. This is the problem with *Smith v Hughes*. The principle of objective
>   interpretation suggests that in order to work out whether the defendant was agreeing to
>   buy old oats, we look at how things ought to have appeared to the claimant. So Smith v
>   Hughes is out of line with orthodox rules of offer and acceptance.

Comment: What does a Van Gogh painting have to do with oats? Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @200_success Orginally, para 2 related to another case which I didn't quote, to reduce the length. I quoted the para on oats, now removed, because it preceded 3.41.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *[this book](http://books.google.cz/books?id=EmtFGKmWa60C&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180&dq=limb%20of%20an%20argument&source=bl&ots=5g065Bx111&sig=F-q3KT8JRfmSyJ-c7BahQ0uxAaI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kYdcVMfsJIe5OL3IgMAM&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=limb%20of%20an%20argument&f=false)* on philosophy, the word  *limb* seems to be used in the sense of one of the legs (i.e., supports) of an argument.

Your excerpt is frim page 64 of the book *The Law of Contract*. On [page 63](http://books.google.cz/books?id=kq1GBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=%22%20did%20not%20think%20that%20the%20shop%20owner%20was%20promising%20that%20it%20was%20a%20Van%20Gogh:%20I%20merely%20hoped%20that%20it%20was%22&source=bl&ots=AiVgEasgaH&sig=yLckpAQN3qik_HoipSfLQQ4prdA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LoZcVJXSFIfJPIXlgQg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22%20did%20not%20think%20that%20the%20shop%20owner%20was%20promising%20that%20it%20was%20a%20Van%20Gogh%3A%20I%20merely%20hoped%20that%20it%20was%22&f=false) of that book, we can read  "A comment can be made on each of the conditions laid down in *Smith v Hughes*. With regard to the first condition ...". It seems to me that the author's discussion of the first condition is the first limb of his argument. If I am right, I think it would been better to have designated it as such. As things are, he introduces a second limb with apparently no reference to a first limb